# Oracle ORA:01031 When Opening RefCursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g, ref-cursor

Upon Executing the Bellow Procedure The Error ORA : 01031 is Thrown.

if you closely look at this code at the end of the procedure

which is

```
"v_strSQL := v_strSQL1||' UNION ALL '||v_strSQL2||' UNION ALL '||v_strSQL3||' 
UNION ALL '||v_strSQL4||' UNION ALL '||v_strSQL5||' UNION ALL '||v_strSQL6;"
```

when i remove union all it works fine but i have to use the union all in my case
which is causing problem (Thanks in Advance)

```
create or replace PROCEDURE  "PR_COUNTS" 
(
  v_CabID1 INT,
  v_CabID2 INT,
  v_ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO VARCHAR2,
  v_EMP_NO VARCHAR2,
  v_USER_ID VARCHAR2,
  v_HRDB VARCHAR2,
  v_SQL INT,
  tbl_cur out sys_refcursor
) AS

v_MainTable VARCHAR2(20);
v_ActionHistory VARCHAR2(30);
v_Assignment VARCHAR2(30);
v_strSQL1 LONG;
v_strSQL2 LONG;
v_strSQL3 LONG;
v_strSQL4 LONG;
v_strSQL5 LONG;
v_strSQL6 LONG;
v_strSQL LONG;
-- SELECT FN_INLOP_SUBJECTS(I.DOCNO) INTO MAIN_SUBJECT FROM DUAL
BEGin
SELECT   MAIN_TABLE INTO V_MainTable FROM OAEFILE_CABINET WHERE CABINETID =     V_CabID1;    
SELECT  ACTION_HST_TABLE INTO V_ActionHistory FROM OAEFILE_CABINET WHERE     CABINETID=V_CabID1;
SELECT  ASSIGNMENT_TABLE INTO V_Assignment FROM OAEFILE_CABINET WHERE     CABINETID=V_CabID1;


v_strSQL1   :=
'
select  1 COL1,
        1 COL2,
        ''Not Yet Accepted'' COL3,''قيود غير مستلمة'' COL4,
        count(1) COL5,
        ''5503'' COL6
from    '||V_MainTable||' 
WHERE   INDOCNO > ''0'' AND
        BAYAN_FLAG = 1 AND 
        FCNTCT_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
        ASSGNCNTCT_ID = '''||V_EMP_NO||''' AND 
        ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO = '''||V_ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO||''' AND
        STATUS_ID IN (2) AND
        DOCDATE BETWEEN 
         CASE 
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 1 THEN SYSDATE-30
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 2 THEN SYSDATE-90
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 3 THEN SYSDATE-365
          END
         AND 
        SYSDATE';

v_strSQL2   :=
'
SELECT  1 COL1,
        2 COL2,
        ''Assigned to Dept'' COL3,''إدارة الوثائق'' COL4,
        COUNT(1) COL5,
        ''309'' COL6
FROM    '||V_MainTable||' 
WHERE   INDOCNO > ''0'' AND
        NUM_FIELD1 IN (0,1) AND 
        BAYAN_FLAG = ''0'' AND
        ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO = '''||V_ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO||''' AND 
        ASSGNCNTCT_ID IN (SELECT EMP_NO FROM HR.EMPLS WHERE DEPT_NO =     '''||V_ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO||''') AND
        STATUS_ID IN (2)  AND
        DOCDATE BETWEEN 
         CASE 
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 1 THEN SYSDATE-30
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 2 THEN SYSDATE-90
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 3 THEN SYSDATE-365
          END
         AND 
        SYSDATE'
;

v_strSQL3   :=
'        
SELECT  1 COL1,
        3 COL2,
        ''Assigned to employees'' COL3,''وثائق تعيين موظف'' COL4,
        COUNT(1) COL5,
        ''309'' COL6
FROM    '||V_MainTable||' 
WHERE   INDOCNO > ''0'' AND
        NUM_FIELD1 IN (0,1) AND 
        BAYAN_FLAG = ''0'' AND
        ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO = '''||V_ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO||''' AND 
        ASSGNCNTCT_ID = '''||V_EMP_NO||''' AND
        STATUS_ID IN (2)  AND
        DOCDATE BETWEEN 
         CASE 
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 1 THEN SYSDATE-30
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 2 THEN SYSDATE-90
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 3 THEN SYSDATE-365
          END
         AND 
        SYSDATE'
;

v_strSQL4   :=
'
SELECT  1 COL1,
        4 COL2,
        ''Rejected Docs'' COL3,''قيود مرفوضة'' COL4,
        COUNT(1) COL5,
        ''5504'' COL6
FROM    '||V_MainTable||' A
JOIN    OAEFILE_PROCESS_TYPE B ON A.PROCESS_ID = B.PROCESS_ID AND     USERDEFINED01 = 7
WHERE   INDOCNO > ''0'' AND
        BAYAN_FLAG = ''0'' AND 
        STATUS_ID IN (2) AND 
        FCNTCT_ID IS NOT NULL AND
        A.ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO = '||V_ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO||' AND
        A.ASSGNCNTCT_ID = '||V_EMP_NO||' AND 
        DOCDATE BETWEEN 
        CASE 
               WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 1 THEN SYSDATE-30
               WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 2 THEN SYSDATE-90
               WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 3 THEN SYSDATE-365
        END
        AND 
        SYSDATE';

v_strSQL5   :=
'
SELECT  1 COL1,        
        5 COL2,        
        ''Late Documents'' COL3,''Late Documents'' COL4,         
        COUNT(1) COL5,
        ''314'' COL6  
FROM   '||V_MainTable||' A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OAEFILE_DOC_SOURCE_TYPE G
  ON  A.DOC_ORIGN_SOURCE   = G.DOC_SOURCE_ID AND 
      G.CABINETID         = '||v_CabID1||'
WHERE   INDOCNO > ''0'' AND
        TO_CHAR(A.REMIND_DATE,''YYYY.MM.DD'')<=     TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,''YYYY.MM.DD'') AND 
        A.STATUS_ID IN (2) AND 
        A.OUTDOCNO = ''0'' AND
        A.ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO = '||V_ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO||' AND
        A.ASSGNCNTCT_ID = '||V_EMP_NO||' AND 
        A.NUM_FIELD1 IN(0) AND 
        FCNTCT_ID IS NOT NULL AND
        DOCDATE BETWEEN 
         CASE 
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 1 THEN SYSDATE-30
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 2 THEN SYSDATE-90
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 3 THEN SYSDATE-365
          END
         AND 
        SYSDATE'
;

v_strSQL6   :=
'
SELECT  1 COL1,        
        6 COL2,        
        ''About to get Late Documents'' COL3,
        ''About to get Late Documents'' COL4,         
        COUNT(1) COL5,
        ''314'' COL6  
FROM   '||V_MainTable||' A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OAEFILE_DOC_SOURCE_TYPE G
  ON  A.DOC_ORIGN_SOURCE   = G.DOC_SOURCE_ID AND 
      G.CABINETID         = '||v_CabID1||'
WHERE   INDOCNO > ''0'' AND
        trunc(SYSDATE) - A.REMIND_DATE = 1 AND 
        A.STATUS_ID IN (2) AND 
        A.OUTDOCNO = ''0'' AND
        A.ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO = '||V_ASSIGNTO_DEPT_NO||' AND
        A.ASSGNCNTCT_ID = '||V_EMP_NO||' AND 
        A.NUM_FIELD1 IN (0) AND 
        FCNTCT_ID IS NOT NULL AND DOCDATE BETWEEN 
         CASE 
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 1 THEN SYSDATE-30
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 2 THEN SYSDATE-90
                WHEN '||v_SQL||' = 3 THEN SYSDATE-365
          END
         AND 
        SYSDATE'
;

v_strSQL := v_strSQL1||' UNION ALL '||v_strSQL2||' UNION ALL '||v_strSQL3||'     UNION ALL '||v_strSQL4||' UNION ALL '||v_strSQL5||' UNION ALL '||v_strSQL6;

open tbl_cur for v_strSQL;

END;
```

Comment: `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`

Comment: Have you tried debugging the statement, e.g. `dbms_output.put_line(v_strSQL)`, and either inspecting it or trying to run it manually? Do you have permissions on all the tables involved, particularly those that are only in the later unioned clauses like OAEFILE_PROCESS_TYPE, granted directly to the procedure owner - not through a role?

Comment: Yes off-course i did debug the statement upon final generation of the script with all unions it is executing fine, The Problem is only when the execution Reaches.  
open tbl_cur for v_strSQL;  yes i do have permissions on all the objects im using in this code

Comment: If you can run the generated statement directly in SQL but it errors when run from within the procedure that really suggests you have permissions granted through a role. From your last comment I'm not sure if you just checked it looked right, or actually tried to run it.